# How to get number of directory items in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to get number of items of specific directory in Node.js

If I get the items like

```
var dirItems = fs.readdirSync(__dirname+'/my_dir');
```

and then get specific item like

```
dirItems[1]
```

everything is ok

But if I try to get their number like

```
dirItems.length
```

or

```
Object.keys(dirItems).length
```

the page doesn't work in the browser

How to get the number of directory items?

---

**UPDATED**

My full code:

```
var http = require('http'),
    fs = require('fs');

http.createServer(function(req, res) {

    var dirItems = fs.readdirSync(__dirname+'/my_dir');

    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.end(dirItems.length);

}).listen(80, 'localhost');
```

Comment: Normally, for security reasons, websites aren't allowed to access directories on the user's computer. The `fs` module won't normally work in a browser.

Comment: @KhauriMcClain I meant `res.end(dirItems.length)` in Node.js

Comment: Are you using `express`? If you log the value of `dirItems.length` before calling `res.end` is the result correct? Also, despite `res.end` accepting arguments, the [express docs](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.end) seems to suggest that it ends the response without passing any data. And maybe you want to use `res.send` or `res.json` instead?

Comment: Please show the code for the ENTIRE request handler that you're trying to make work.  We need to see the entire context here.  What you've shown in your question does not make sense by itself so we need to see a bigger picture to see where else things are going wrong.

Comment: @jfriend00 I've added the full code to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the error nyou get.

`res.end()` for the basic http server class is very picky about what you send it.  You must give it a ***string*** (the error you got should have been a big clue here).

So, change this:

```
res.end(dirItems.length);
```

to this:

```
res.end(dirItems.length.toString());
```

And, it works for me.  I was able to reproduce your original error and then make it work by making this simple change.

Logically, you can only send string data as an http response so apparently `res.end()` isn't smart enough to attempt a string conversion on its own.  You have to do it yourself.

FYI, if you use a higher level framework like Express, it is more tolerant of what you send it (it will attempt a string conversion in a situation like this).

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would do it:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const dir = './somedir';

fs.readdir(dir, (err, files) => {
  console.log(files.length);
});
```

Comment: If I try `fs.readdir(__dirname+'/my_dir', (err, files) => {res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});res.end(files.length);});` the page still doesn't work

Comment: So you want to read the files and display them on the page, is that it?

Comment: Yes, I want to get their number, do something with the number and then display on the page

Comment: @stckvrw Well, you would need a server runnuning, something like express, where you will have a function that get the files, and I would probably do something like reading the file and appending the stream to an HTML element and display the element with the page info rather than the page itself, or something like that.